# Swift: Size of UIImage when slicing enabled

Tags: swift, uiimage, size, slice

When I slice the image in the assets folder in Xcode, the `size` property of the UIImage returns a wrong value. Does anyone know how to get the real image size when the slicing is enabled? Does not matter if size will be in pixels or in points.

Or maybe there is a way to get the size of the image's rounded part so that I could add the cap insets in code?

This is how I slice the image in Xcode:

[image]

Or, maybe there is a way to find the size of the highlighted (darker) part of the image?

I would appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

When "slicing" an image in assets, you don't need to set the cap insets -- it's done automatically.

If you really *need* to get the "slice" values, you can read them via the `.capInsets` property:

```
    guard let img = UIImage(named: "sliced") else { return }
    print("image size:", img.size)
    print("caps insets:", img.capInsets)
```

My quick test - of a 200 x 60 "capsule" image with 20-pixel corner radius - using the default slicing outputs:

```
image size: (39.0, 60.0)
caps insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 19.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 19.0)
```

So, the **width** is the left-inset plus the right-inset plus 1 (one) ... Because the center portion will stretch to fit, the "default* width of that section is `1`.